# javacv works with 32-bit but gives unsatisfiedLinkError with 64-bit opencv?

Tags: opencv, javacv

I am copying the dlls into the current directory, so it should not be a case of adding it to the path. What i am confused with is, is copying the dlls in the current directory enough? It works fine with 32-bit and not with 64-bit and all i am changing is the opencv dll files.